# Is this closure? What might be the point of this?

Tags: javascript, closures, anonymous-function

I am fairly new to Javascript and I have picked up a codebase in which I see the following snippet:

```
if (DEBUG == false) { // WHAT S ALL THIS?!!
    while ((request = UrlS.pop()) != null) {
      (function() {
        var counterDB = (function() {
          var id = 0;
          return function() {
            return id++;
          }; // Return and increment
        })();
        var tw = items[num];
        console.log("Request " + request);
        getFeed(request, tw, httpRequestCallback, counterDB);
      })();
    }
  } else { // WHAT S ALL THIS?!! #2
    (function() {
      var counterDB = (function() {
        var id = 0;
        return function() {
          return id++;
        }; // Return and increment
      })();
      var tw = items[num];
      request = UrlS.pop();
      getFeed(request, tw, httpRequestCallback, counterDB);
    })();
  }
```

Especially around the `counterDB` var, **what is the point of creating so many nested anonymous functions?**

with a quick search, i found that it is used elsewhere for a check: `

```
if(counterDB()<maximumSolutions)`
```

why all this? why not just `CurrentModule.increment()` or smth?

Comment: see: [What is the (function() { } )() construct in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

Comment: Those inner IEFEs are quite pointless, the outer one (the loop body) would be required to get different `id` variable with different `counterDB` functions in the loop.

Comment: from the ref question of @charlietfl: "This pattern is often used when trying to avoid polluting the global namespace " cool! but is this it?

Comment: @Bergi i m afraid i didnT get it. could you elaborate with an answer pls?

Comment: Bergi is saying that the counterDB function is always going to return the same value because it's being reinitialized with every loop. However @Bergi `getFeed` could be callling that function multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

The `IIFE` assigned to variable `counterDB` closes variable `id` within it. It is a way by which you make variable `id` private to that `IIFE`. By doing this you make variable `id` accessible only from within `IIFE`. And that is why the function returned by `IIFE` can increment(or change) its value.

This will also avoid global namespace pollution since variable `id` is not accessible outside and thus no other function or stmt can change its value (which can happen by mistake).